# combobox splitting values up to 1 char and only getting the first value from json

Tags: c#, xaml

i am trying to populate my combobox with a json string with around 30 values

but it only takes the first value (4x98) and splitting it up so it is

- 4
- x
- 9
- 8

  ```
     private void bindkrydsmål()
    {
  {
      try
      {
          string Url = URL_Domain + "resources/bolt-pattern";
          Uri serviceUri = new Uri(Url);
          using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
          {
              webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
              string api = webClient.DownloadString(serviceUri);

              List<boltPatterns> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<boltPatterns>>(api);
              comboBox_Copy.DataContext = values;
          }
      }

      catch (Exception es)
      {

      }
  }
  }
   public class boltPatterns
    {           
      public string BoltPattern { get; set; }
    }
  ```

combobox xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_Copy" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BoltPattern}" Width="150" Height="40" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" Background="#FF303030" FontSize="16"  Canvas.Left="1030" Canvas.Top="24" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTest2}">
```

api value

```
"[{\"BoltPattern\":\"4x98\"},{\"BoltPattern\":\"5x108\"},{\"BoltPattern\":\"5x114.3\"},{\"BoltPattern\":\"6x180\"},{\"BoltPattern\":\"4x100\"},{\"BoltPattern\":\"8x165.1\"},{\"BoltPattern\":\"5x100\"},{\"BoltPattern\":\"5x165\"},{\"BoltPattern\":\"5x120.65\"},{\"BoltPattern\":\"6x115\"},{\"BoltPattern\":\"6x127\"},{\"BoltPattern\":\"5x118\"},{\"BoltPattern\":\"5x150\"},{\"BoltPattern\":\"5x127\"},{\"BoltPattern\":null}]"
```

Comment: Show the value for `api`

Comment: updatet with the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just need a property name to bind. Rest all is fine

```
DisplayMemberPath="BoltPattern"
```

and

```
comboBox_Copy.ItemsSource= values;
```